# Jquery Autocomplete not loading

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, jquery-ui

The autocomplete function is attached to this Input field with id="search". When I type in text, nothing shows up, contrary to the search results that showed up a few times before I used Jquery UI calendar on another textfield in another file.

The Developer console in CHROME and Firebug in Firefox show no error, and display "XHR finished loading" instead. I don't know what went wrong! Please help.

default.php

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="myfunctions.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>

    <div id="search_container"><input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)"  id="search" placeholder="Search here"/></div>
```

myfunctions.js

```
function showHint(strvalue)
{
   $("#search").autocomplete({
       minLength:2,
     source: "getHint.php?search="+strvalue,
     select:function(ui)
              {
                  log(ui.item?
                  window.location.replace(ui.item.link):
                  "Not Found");
              }
    }
         ).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
return $("<li></li>")
         .data("item.autocomplete", item)
         .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
         .appendTo(ul);
 };
}
```

getHint.php

```
<?php
require_once 'myfunctions.php';
$search=sanitizeString($_GET['search']);
$query="Select * from students where firstname like '%$search%' or lastname like '%$search% order by firstname'";
$result=  queryMysql($query);
$k=0;
while($row=  mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $email=$row['email'];
    $name=nameOf($email);
    $studentid=studentidOf($email);
    $as[]['label']="<a style='text-decoration:none' href='student_profile.php?studentid=$studentid'><div class='search_elements'><span class='search_elements_span'>$name</span></div></a>";
    $as[$k++]['value']=$name;

}

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode($as);
```

main.css

```
#search_container
{
position: relative;
top:1px;
left:750px;
width:250px;

}

#search
{
font-family: cursive;
font-size: 14px;
color: #999999;
width:250px;
position:relative;
background: white;
z-index: 11;
top: 1px;
}

#search:focus
{

font-family: cursive;
font-size: 14px;
width: 250px;
color: black;
}
```

On inspecting code in the browser, the input textarea shows following after i search for an item:

```
<input id="searchstr" class="ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" placeholder="Search here" name="searchstr" autocomplete="off"></input>
```

Why's the autocomplete attribute set to "off"??

Comment: Did you check content of AJAX request? Response with header 200 OK doesn't mean that the response is fine.

Comment: @Mathletics The input text area has the id 'search'

Comment: @dragoste - Yes, I have checked all the queries manually on MySQL. Moreover, the autocomplete search worked fine once, and I haven't made any changes in the PHP file thereafter!

Comment: I find it curious that you're setting up the autocomplete widget on the first keypress, rather than initializing it with the DOM. Is it necessary that you set it up that way?

Comment: I tried the other way around, by including the autocomplete as a JQuery function in the same "default.php". Now that doesn't work either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file 'myfunctions.php' required by getHint.php was printing data. The getHint.php file shouldn't print or 'echo' anything if it has to encode an array or data in the form of JSON.

Removing the printing data from 'myfunctions.php' worked amazingly well.
The JSON encoded data can be checked through FIREBUG application in Mozilla Firefox.